# Using Block sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b)

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks, sorteddictionary

In my project, I try to compare a known location to an inputted location by using block sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b). I have a dictionary array called locationArray containing a lat long and a station number that corresponds to that lat long point. I try to compare each locationArray station to the inputted station. I do this by taking the absolute value of the difference between the two which gives me a distance. Then I try to sort locationArray based on the distance from the inputted station from closest to furthest away.

```
//locationArray

#define kStation @"station"
#define kLatitude @"latitude"
#define kLongitude @"longitude"




NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"499CSV" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *csvString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray *locations = [csvString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray *CSVArray = [NSMutableArray array];


NSCharacterSet *whiteSPNewLine = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
for (NSString * location in locations)
{

NSArray *components = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double latitude   = [[components[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine] doubleValue];
double longitude  = [[components[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine] doubleValue];
NSString *station = [components[2] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine];

NSDictionary *dict = @{kLatitude: @(latitude),
                       kLongitude: @(longitude),
                       kStation: station};

[CSVArray addObject:dict];

}

NSLog(@"The contents of CSVArray = %@",[CSVArray description]);


{
    latitude = "41.674364";
    longitude = "-81.23700700000001";
    station = 40150;
},
    {
    latitude = "41.67517";
    longitude = "-81.235038";
    station = 40763;
},
    {
    latitude = "41.673106";
    longitude = "-81.24017499999999";
    station = 39175;
}, ...
```

My block code that directly follows locationArray.

```
NSArray *orderedPlaces = [CSVArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {

NSDictionary *dictA;
NSDictionary *dictB;

NSString *locA;
NSString *locB;

int distanceA;
int distanceB;


dictA = (NSDictionary *)a;
dictB = (NSDictionary *)b;

NSLog(@"dictA = %@", dictA);
NSLog(@"dictB = %@", dictB);


locA = [dictA objectForKey:kStation];
locB = [dictB objectForKey:kStation];

NSLog(@"locA = %@", locA);
NSLog(@"locB = %@", locB);



distanceA = abs(stationNumber-[locA intValue]);
distanceB = abs(stationNumber-[locB intValue]);

NSLog(@"distanceA = %d", distanceA);
NSLog(@"distanceB = %d", distanceB);

if (distanceA < distanceB) {
  return NSOrderedAscending;
} else if (distanceA > distanceB) {
  return NSOrderedDescending;
} else {
  return NSOrderedSame;
}


}];

NSLog(@"The contents of array = %@",[orderedPlaces description]);
```

The block runs but it's not sorting locationsArray as intended. orderedPlaces returns an unsorted locationsArray. By running NSLOG on the block components, I see that it successfully recognizes locationsArray and creates the distance object. I must be missing something because I use the same code in a different part of my project where I compare locationsArray to the lat long of the user's location and it works well. Please help me identify the issue keeping it from working as intended.

*If you need any more information or clarification, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your sort block. You're calculating distance A as abs(stationNumber-[locA intValue]).

What is stationNumber? Is that some fixed integer index? How can the difference between a fixed station number and the station numbers in your array have anything to do with distances?

It seems to me that your distance values should be 
(target.lat - this_station.lat)^2 + (target.long - this_station.long)^2

That will give you the square of the pythagorean distance between your target point and one of the stations you are comparing. Then in your comparison you select the item who's distance squared is less.

You can skip the square root, because you're just comparing them. That will make your distance calculations much faster.

Comment: A station number is a precise point along a roadway design so station 10000 is 100 ft from station 10100 for example. The only dictionary object I really care about is the one who's station is closest to the inputted station and I want that dictionary object to be the first (objectAtIndex:0) object in orderedArray. I use the distance value to compare the proximity from the inputted station to all the stations in locationArray so the one with the shortest distance will be the closest. The abs value makes sure large negative numbers don't get mistook to be the closest.Please bear with me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *orderedPlaces = [CSVArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
```

`^(id a, id b)` means `^void (id a, id b)` and your return value is ignored.

Comment: "^(id a, id b) means ^void (id a, id b)" No it isn't. The return type is inferred.

Comment: That's right. From http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html :The return type is optional and is inferred from the return statements. If the return statements return a value, they all must return a value of the same type. If there is no value returned the inferred type of the Block is void; otherwise it is the type of the return statement value.